# How to change Running State VM date with PowerShell?

Tags: virtual-machine, powershell, hyper-v

I have few hyper-v vms that I need to change the datetime when it is running.

When it is off changing the date is useless since hyper-v synchronizes the date with host when it starts even if the sync-date in settings is setup to false.

any directions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to uncheck the **Time synchronization** option from the **Integration Services** settings of the VM in Hyper-V, and set each VM to synchronize their times from a reliable source manually one by one or force all domain computers to use NTP from a domain controller.

I had an issue with a Hyper-V Server once that wasn't configured properly for NTP and the time on it got out of whack due to the **Time synchronization** setting being checked so I unchecked that option on the Hyper-V host, and then set the important VMs to sync their time from a DC instead.

The issue with the Hyper-V server in my case had to do with a CMOS battery or something along those lines where the time was getting out of whack or whatever, but that got fixed eventually too but leaving the **Time synchronization** option unchecked never caused any issues with any VMs since I set those up to get NTP from another more reliable source.

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [Windows Time Service Tools and Settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings)
- [Configure DC to synchronize time with external NTP server](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/65413-configure-dc-to-synchronize-time-with-external-ntp-server)